# Stack Overflow questions fail to load in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I cannot load any questions from Stack Overflow in the Android app (version 1.0.89), but I can load questions from any other site.

When I go to Stack Overflow site from the navigation panel on the left, it doesn't load any questions. I have tried to show new, unanswered, etc., but none show any results.

I can search for questions with the search bar, which shows a list of results, but I cannot open any because it says "failed to load question". (Clicking retry just shows the same error again.)

Is this a bug everyone is experiencing? Or is it just me? I tried to clear data of the app and even uninstall it, but it didn't help.

(Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that my account was recently suspended? But it worked fine during the suspension period.)

**Edit**

I logged myself out of the app, and continued as guest. I find that when I was using it as guest everything worked fine. Then I tried to upvote an answer so it would prompt me to sign in and return to the question, but when I signed in, the app stopped. Then everything stopped working again.

**Edit 2**

It surprisingly started working again. Coincidentally, I was suspended exactly 2 weeks ago for a week, so it started working again after double the length of my account suspension. To me it sounds like something wrong with the suspension handling by the servers... I'm not sure...

Comment: No repro. Same app version.

Comment: No repro, also suspension shouldn't prevent opening and reading any questions.